# How do I allow multiple checkbox onClick event handlers in different Javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of checkboxes in an HTML file.
Then I have `onClick()` event handlers in two separate JavaScript files.
I just noticed that only one of of my `onClick` methods is being called when I click on the checkboxes. If I remove one of the event handlers then then other one will work. There must be some way to get a click event and not swallow the event for other listeners.

How do I allow both of the event handlers to be called?

```
        var at = document.getElementById("at");
        at.onclick = function() {
```

Comment: that is because your first callback is being replaced by the last one. you should see @chiliNUT 's answer,

and also you should probably also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning to `onclick` will overwrite whatever was there before. If you want to stack events, Use `addEventListener` in native JS or jQuery `.on("click"`

**JS**

```
var at = document.getElementById("at");
at.addEventListener("click", function() { //whatever
                                        }, false);
at.addEventListener("click", function() { //some other function
                                        }, false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

**jQuery**

```
$('#at').on("click", function() {//whatever
                                })
        .on("click", function() {//some other function
                                });
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Indeed. Also, if you want to stop event execution from some onclick event, you can call `event.stopPropagation()` [https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)